# how to split arraylist and store in a var in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, split

I have an array list that I need to split by its delimiter "," and store in a variable/string, however I cannot split it successfully.

```
the values will be. 
arr[0] = "1", "Illinois","Seattle"
arr[1] = "2", "Michigan", "New York"
arr[2] = "3", "Spain", "Italy"
```

Comment: What is you array list? What is the type of `arr`? Is it also an array, or a string, or what?

Comment: What exactly do you want to get out in which form? This is not clear to me.

Comment: @jbaDaniel `arr[0] = "1", "Illinois","Seattle"` is not a valid assignment in C#. What are your data inputs, and what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it this way. :)

```
string[] sdata = selecteddetails[0].ToString().Split(',');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var res = arr.SelectMany(i => i.Split(',')).ToArray();
```